# Creando listas dentro de ciclos for

Tags: r, bucle-for

Tengo la lista movA con 100 tablas en su interior.
Cada tabla tiene la columna VelaSignal, y con cada valor de esa columna debo hacer una comparación de valores. Por lo tanto, para cada valor creo un vector de V o F, que guardo en un objeto llamado a.
Mi intención es luego guardar cada uno de esos vectores generados en una lista, vof, cuyos objetos están asociadas a cada tabla en movA, pero no he podido hacerlo.
El código hasta el momento es el siguiente:

```
a = c()
vof = list()
for (k in seq_along(moviA)) {
  for (i in moviA[[k]]$Nmov) {
    for (j in moviA[[k]]$VelaSignal[i]:dim(criptolista[[k]])[1]) {
      m = criptolista[[k]]$high[j+1]>criptolista[[k]]$high[moviA[[k]]$VelaSignal[i]-1]
      a[j-moviA[[k]]$VelaSignal[i]+1] = m
      
    }
    vof[[k]][i] = a
  }
}
```

Al compilar recibo el error **Error in `*tmp*`[[k]] : subíndice fuera de  los límites**.

Espero puedan guiarme en cómo solucionar el error, y en darme algún consejo de cómo evitar tantos ciclos for, pues la ejecución es muy lenta.

Gracias!!!

Comment: Revisa `criptolista`, no debe tener la misma cantidad de elementos de `MoviA`. Por otro lado, por que no enfocas tu pregunta al problema y no a la solución? tal vez exista una solución  mucho más simple, pero sin conocer bien el problema va a ser difícil ayudarte

Comment: Además esto esta mal: `vof[[k]][i] = a` ¿Qué es lo que buscas con esto?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, hola. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. El problema sí debe estar en vof[[k]][i], porque si no incluyo esa línea el código funciona, pero solamente guarda la última iteración, y necesito que cada vez que haga una iteración, el vector a se guarde en la posición i de la tabla k de la lista vof.

Comment: Pero es que vof es una lista en principio sin elementos, si haces `vof[[k]][i]` estas accediendo a una posicion de un lista vacia, primero inserta el elemento o inicializa un vector con valores dummy haciendo `vof[[k]] <- nuevo_elemento` y luego accede a `nuevo_elemento` mediante `vof[[k]] [i]`

Comment: Es como hacer esto: `vof = list();vof[[1]][1]=0`